# How to refresh tkinter Threeview for the height of heading

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Try to set heading of Treeview to 3-line height. Following code to demo this issue.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()

font = ('Courier New', 10)
tkfont = Font(family=font[0], size=font[1])
width, height = tkfont.measure('W'), tkfont.metrics("linespace")

headings = ['A1', 'B1\nB2', 'C1\nC2\nC3']
data = [('A', [1,2,3]), ('B', [2,4,6]), ('C', [3,6,9])]

treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=headings, displaycolumns=headings,
    show='tree headings', height=4)
for i, heading in enumerate(headings):
    treeview.heading(heading, text=heading)
    treeview.column(heading, width=width*4, minwidth=10, anchor=tk.CENTER)
for i, (text, value) in enumerate(data):
    treeview.insert('', i, text=text, value=value)
treeview.pack()

#treeview.heading('#0', text='\nHello World\n')

def callback():
    treeview.heading('#0', text='\nHello World\n')
    """ Add following statement(s) still not work
    treeview.update()
    treeview.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    root.update_idletasks()
    """

button = tk.Button(root, text='Change', command=callback)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Case 1, use button `Change` to call `#treeview.heading('#0', text='\nHello World\n')`, it doesn't work.

[image]

Case 2, remove the `#` from the line `treeview.heading('#0', text='\nHello World\n')`, it work.

[image]

My question here is

- what's the difference for these two cases, and
- How to refresh the Treeview in case 1 to get same result as in case 2.

Comment: It looks like the table header height is calculated based on cell 0, therefore, a workaround without using styles - tree_view.heading('#0', text=' \n\n') with space.

Comment: I did use this work around, but my question is that call it at different place get different result, why they different and how they can be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one method for it, set the style for treeview widget, and it work.

```py
def callback():
    treeview.heading('#0', text='\nHello World\n')
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure('Treeview.Heading', foreground='black')
```